# R grep pattern regex with brackets

Tags: r, regex

I have a problem with grep in R:

```
patterns= c("AB_(1)","AB_(2)")
text= c("AB_(1)","DDD","CC")

grep(patterns[1],text)
>integer(0)  ????
```

the grep command has problem with "()" brackets, is there any as.XX(patterns[1]) that I can use??

Comment: JFI, brackets `()` in regexps are used to extract matched substrings. see ?gsub, *Examples* section.

Answer (score 36):

You need escape by double backslash:

```
> patterns= c("AB_\\(1\\)","AB_(2)")
> text= c("AB_(1)","DDD","CC")
> 
> grep(patterns[1],text)
[1] 1
```

Comment: @user170322. There is also a bit different way. If patterns are just plain text (as seems likely), parameter `fixed` of `grep` could be very useful (so, providing `fixed=TRUE` and not escaping `()` with double backslash

Comment: What if I get patterns from the database?

Answer (score 19):

If there are no special pattern matching characters in the regular expression (as is the case in the example shown in the question) then use `fixed=TRUE`:

```
grep(patterns[1], text, fixed = TRUE)
```