# Error with R package HiveR: Error in HPD$edges$id2[n] <- grep(pat2, HPD$nodes$lab) : replacement has length zero

Tags: r

I'm trying to draw the hive plots and thus visualize a network. I'm using the "HiveR" package. This is my code:

```
library(HiveR)
hive1 <- edge2HPD(edge_df = relations_tot)
```

but I obtained the following error:

```
Error in HPD$edges$id2[n] <- grep(pat2, HPD$nodes$lab) : 
  replacement has length zero
```

My dataset is:

```
> dput(relations_tot)
structure(list(lab1 = c("Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
"Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
"Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
"Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Belgium", 
"Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
"Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
"Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
"Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
"Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
"Belgium", "Belgium", "Cyprus", "Cyprus", "Cyprus", "Cyprus", 
"Cyprus", "Cyprus", "Cyprus", "Cyprus", "Cyprus", "Cyprus", "Cyprus", 
"Cyprus", "Cyprus", "Cyprus", "Cyprus", "Estonia", "Estonia", 
"Estonia", "Estonia", "Estonia", "Estonia", "Estonia", "Estonia", 
"Estonia", "Estonia", "Estonia", "Finland", "Finland", "Finland", 
"Finland", "Finland", "Finland", "Finland", "Finland", "Finland", 
"Finland", "Finland", "Finland", "Finland", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France"), lab2 = c("Finland", 
"Germany", "Greece", "Italy", "Latvia", "Netherlands", "Slovakia", 
"Slovenia", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Denmark", "Hungary", "Poland", 
"Romania", "Sweden", "United Kingdom", "Africa", "Asia", "Europe (rest of)", 
"North America", "South America", "Austria", "Cyprus", "Estonia", 
"Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Ireland", "Italy", 
"Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands", 
"Portugal", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", 
"Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Hungary", "Poland", "Romania", 
"Sweden", "United Kingdom", "Africa", "Asia", "Europe (rest of)", 
"North America", "Oceania ", "South America", "Austria", "Belgium", 
"France", "Germany", "Greece", "Latvia", "Malta", "Netherlands", 
"Spain", "Africa", "Asia", "Europe (rest of)", "North America", 
"Oceania ", "South America", "Austria", "Finland", "Latvia", 
"Lithuania", "Netherlands", "Denmark", "Sweden", "United Kingdom", 
"Africa", "Europe (rest of)", "North America", "Belgium", "Estonia", 
"Germany", "Italy", "Latvia", "Netherlands", "Denmark", "Sweden", 
"United Kingdom", "Africa", "Asia", "Europe (rest of)", "South America", 
"Austria", "Belgium", "Germany", "Greece", "Ireland", "Italy", 
"Lithuania"), weight = c(1289230, 570990, 1490, 831013, 1085.99999999999, 
3203, 669, 4904, 293468, 2568, 290, 87319, 22525, 1529, 63118, 
15492, 38605, 40154.9999999999, 546517, 33217, 389, 171838, 2092788, 
4540193, 3622359, 109906515, 234046234, 4574268, 1903145, 60966459, 
1195178, 19822660, 95858806, 225985, 204163356, 31413980, 912207, 
487192, 54082177, 3919672, 7418114, 28661212, 4477883, 2138933, 
182520811, 46548202.9999999, 12146816, 30102392.9999999, 18650084, 
140902264, 191564127, 13024827, 6892758, 1667997, 479381, 24555, 
403645.999999999, 5062028, 3121531, 1919599, 391523, 39, 86360, 
1828518, 29985695, 3965455, 668100, 488828.999999999, 211750.999999999, 
11055, 3629498, 394460, 885.999999999999, 107, 915.999999999999, 
293220, 17, 55415, 72889, 6911, 7707, 1733272, 15606, 35273, 
210, 13813, 148, 52928, 8, 30998, 86, 314416, 152, 127728, 32827032, 
21213714, 6768593.99999999, 92478, 8853066, 5598)), row.names = c(4L, 
6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 
53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 
66L, 67L, 68L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 76L, 79L, 80L, 84L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 
97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 103L, 109L, 110L, 113L, 121L, 125L, 126L, 
127L, 129L, 130L, 134L, 136L, 138L, 141L, 142L, 146L, 154L, 158L, 
159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 
176L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related to this :  [R grep pattern regex with brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992436/r-grep-pattern-regex-with-brackets)

`grep` can't deal with regex with parethesis with your function.

When `lab1` or `lab2 == "Europe (rest of)"`, then no match is returned.

I suggest you to replace "Europe (rest of)" with "Rest of Europe" in your dataframe before running `edge2HPD` for instance, using `str_replace`.