# How to extract using REGEX in R for a ]

Tags: r, stringr

I have a column that has many rows.
the column has a value like

[Testing Data 123-INDEPENDENCE, MO] 99 *2-5PLT

I want to write str_extract to extract everything after ]
so the output should be 99 *2-5PLT.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R grep pattern regex with brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992436/r-grep-pattern-regex-with-brackets)

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? You seem to have a sense that brackets need special treatment, so what did you do with that?

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
a <- "[Testing Data 123-INDEPENDENCE, MO] 99 *2-5PLT"
str_extract(a, "(?<=\\] )(.*)")

[1] "99 *2-5PLT"
```

Here we use a lookbehind to find the closing bracket (also the trailing space), then match everything after:

https://regex101.com/r/Aq9D1p/1

Edit, you could also do something like:

```
a %>% str_split_fixed(., "] ", n = 2)

     [,1]                                 [,2]        
[1,] "[Testing Data 123-INDEPENDENCE, MO" "99 *2-5PLT"
```

Comment: For the 'also do' the leading '[' likely would also be removed, and perhaps 'space' replaced by '_' or '-', though the OP doesn't specify; once the first hurdle is crossed, the next might come up.

Answer (score 1):

Also a base R solution:

```
regmatches(a, regexpr("\\[[^[]*\\]\\s+\\K.*", a, perl = TRUE))

"99 *2-5PLT"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can drop everything till `]`.

Using `sub` in base R -

```
x <- "[Testing Data 123-INDEPENDENCE, MO] 99 *2-5PLT"
sub('.*\\]\\s+', '', x)
#[1] "99 *2-5PLT"
```

Similarly, with `stringr::str_remove` -

```
stringr::str_remove(x, '.*\\]\\s+')
```